# Why is my item drop only 170%

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I currently have two durable collector catalogs applied and it is only saying 170% on item drop. I see people have 320% on rare item drop and 500% on normal item drop. Why isn't my item drop the same? What can I do to raise it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are playing on easy mode.

in easy mode you gain less items and cannot get rare items.
this makes it impossible to gain some of the rare components needed to craft the best weapons in game.

Comment: Does this mean that I can't unlock the two best weapons in the game unless I play on normal mode?

Comment: Yes because Trapezohedrons are rare items